# is it possible to pass a variable when a link will toggle open a modal?

Tags: php

is it possible to pass a variable in a link that toggles open a modal?

i would like to do it with $_GET ,  or $_POST

a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal30' href=

Comment: what is `data-toggle` and `data-target`?

Comment: I believe he is using twitter bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

No, all PHP server processing is done before the page even loads for the client. You would require AJAX to achieve this, then populate the modal and initiate it.

Ultimately this depends on your requirements, whether you want it called before page load, or after page load.

With Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 -- I use session variables to call a modal before page load and have replaced the default javascript `alert()` function with my own

Example to set Modal

```
$_SESSION['_Modal'] = "Success!|##|Your changes have been successfully applied!";
header("Location: page/they/came/from.php");
die();
```

Contents of "/page/they/came/from.php"

```
if (isset($_SESSION['_Modal'])) {
    $msg = addslashes($_SESSION['_Modal']);
    echo '<script>alert("'.$msg.'");</script>';
    unset($_SESSION['_Modal']);
}
```

Javascript for alert() replacement:

```
function alert(msg) {

    $('#aModal').remove();

    var parts = msg.split("|##|");

    var modal = '<div class="modal fade" id="aModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="aModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">' +
                    '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
                        '<div class="modal-content">' +
                            '<div class="modal-header">' +
                                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>' +
                                '<h4 class="modal-title" id="aModalLabel">' + parts[0] + '</h4>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="modal-body">' + parts[1] + '</div>' +
                            '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                                '<button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>';

    $('body').prepend(modal);
    $('#aModal').modal({
        //backdrop: 'static',
        //keyboard: false
    });


}
```

I have also replaced the javascript `confirm()` function

Example Link

```
<a data-href='go/here/if/confirmed.php' data-confirm='Are you sure you wish to delete this?'>
```

Javascript code for `confirm()` replacement

```
$('[data-confirm]').click(function(ev) {
    var href = $(this).attr('data-href');

    if (!$('#dataConfirmModal').length) {
        $('body').append('<div id="dataConfirmModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h4 id="dataConfirmLabel">Please Confirm</h4></div><div class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button><a class="btn btn-primary" id="dataConfirmOK">OK</a></div></div></div></div>');
    } 

    $('#dataConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').html($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
    $('#dataConfirmOK').attr('href', href);
    $('#dataConfirmOK').click(function() {
        $('#dataConfirmModal').fadeOut(300);
        return true;
    })
    $('#dataConfirmModal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
    });
    return false;
});
```